# Вывести слова из предложения php

Tags: php, laravel, php7, unicode

Почему при выводе слов:

```
preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+)/',$request->words, $word);
for ($i=0; $i < count($word[1]); $i++) echo $word[1][$i]."<br>";
```

Выводит следующее:

```
РёРІР°РЅ
РїпїЅ
РєРѕР·РµР»
РёРІР°РЅ, РїС†, РєРѕР·РµР»
```

Если просто вывожу `$request->words`, то все нормально.

Comment: Объясните что вы пытаетесь сделать, именно в цикле, и почему вы используете `preg_match_all`, а потом делаете `$i < count($word[1])`, почему не `$word[0]` или не `$word[2]`?

Comment: есть строка со словами через запятую, мне нужно вывести эти слова по одному

Comment: Т.е. получается, в `$request->words` хранится строка вида `яблоко,груша,банан` и вам нужно вывести эти слова по одному?

Comment: да, именно так, но чего-то сбивается кодировка

Answer (score 0):

Кодировка может сбиваться из-за настроек вашего веб сервера. В данном случаем вам требуется вывести по отдельности все слова из строки `$request->words`. Могу предложить вам воспользоваться следующим кодом:

```
$words = explode(',', $request->words);

foreach($words as $word) {
    echo "$word\n";
}
```

Это поможет вам в вашей проблеме.

Если вы хотите проверять через регулярное выражение, то более правильный подход будет следующим:

```
$words = explode(',', $request->words);

foreach($words as $word) {

    if(preg_match("/([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+)/", $word)) {
        echo "$word\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: хм, все ровно выводит вот так РёРІР°РЅ РїС† РєРѕР·РµР» РёРІР°РЅ, РїС†, РєРѕР·РµР», именно после разбора строки

Comment: Добавьте сверху страницы `header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: Убедитесь что в переменную `$request->words` приходит строка в нужной вам кодировке, возможно вам просто не хватает заголовков в запросе

Comment: $request->words выдает в норм кодирровке

Comment: Добавить `header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');` пробовали?